# Uninstall NIC driver with batch file in windows 7

Tags: batch-file, windows-7, uninstallation, drivers, wmic

I am trying to remotely uninstall the NIC driver so that I can install an updated one. Unfortunately, I can't just install the new one on top of the old one. I actually have to remove the current driver. I'm a good bit of distance from the PC, so I can't do it locally. I've been trying with WMIC but having trouble.

Here is what I was trying to use:

```
wmic sysdriver where name="Intel(R) 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection" delete
```

Then it comes back as "No Instance(s) Available"

Is that name completely wrong? Is there a better way to do this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: `wmic sysdriver list|find "82579"` and see what the name really is.

Comment: The `"Intel(R) 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection"` string poses `Caption` property, not `Name` one. Check `wmic sysdriver get /value|find "Intel"`.